# How to avoid buying chestnuts that are green or rotten on the inside?

Tags: shopping, chestnuts

Hello I live in Wisconsin and bought some Chestnuts imported from Italy early December from a grocery store. I noticed while I was scoring them that majority of them were green or powdery inside I assume this means they were rotting.

When I bought them from the grocery, they were sold next to other holiday nuts in a open air basket.

Is there anything I can watch out for to buy good Chestnuts?

Comment: After decades of trying, my conclusion is you must buy them in a place that sells a lot of them so they are always fresh. Where I live that means an Asian market.

Comment: Or buy the pre-shelled vacuum/foil packed ones. Which don't have any "roasting on an open fire" prospects.